# Apache NiFi PutFile processor not writing to Windows Shared path

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a NiFi instance running on my local Windows workstation.
I want to copy a flow file to a shared network drive: \\sharedpath\files\destination

I am able to use the PutFile processor to copy the file to C:\Temp\Files for example on my C drive.
But PutFile doesn't work with Windows shared network path such as \\sharedpath\files\destination.

The error message is linked here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiK5T.jpg

Comment: Are you able to access that NFS from your Windows machine?

Comment: Yes I am able to. Works ok when I browse, create files etc from my machine, but doesn't seem to work from NiFi for some reason

Comment: Can you please check NiFi logs for detailed stack trace

Comment: Found the issue. The shared path is on an internal network, even though NiFi has access to that, for some reason, it does not write to that directory. I deployed NiFi on a server in that internal network and it seems to be working ok. Not sure how to get around this yet, but my requirement is to have NiFi on the same network anyway, was just trying out from my laptop.